# how to set width in Ckeditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

how to set width for below ckeditor
[image]

Please help on this!

Comment: Follow this [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_size)

Comment: its not working..

Comment: you need to set the width of the entire editor or just the editable area ?

Comment: What's the problem? Can you create jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! but need that code to inspect that specific area actually or you can try by yourself, check  `float:right` from inherit code coming from somewhere i guess. what you can do inspect that specific area and add  `float:none !important`.

this class is taking care of editor tool bar styling and when you change float property it creating same thing as you are showing above.

```
.cke_reset_all, .cke_reset_all *, .cke_reset_all a, .cke_reset_all textarea {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
background: transparent;
text-decoration: none;
width: auto;
height: auto;
vertical-align: baseline;
box-sizing: content-box;
position: static;
transition: none;
border-collapse: collapse;
font: normal normal normal 12px Arial,Helvetica,Tahoma,Verdana,Sans-Serif;
color: #000;
text-align: left;
white-space: nowrap;
cursor: auto;
float: none;}
```

Good Luck